# Passing a variable from the .aspx.cs file to the .aspx file to be displayed?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to get the user's name and surname from active directory using the following code:

**Default.aspx.cs:**

```
public partial class _Default : Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // get the user's name from active dirctory
        var user = UserPrincipal.Current;

        string firstName = user.GivenName;
        string lastName = user.Surname;
    }
}
```

**Default.aspx:**

```
<p class="text-center"><strong><% =firstName =lastName %></strong></p>
```

However, I get an error saying the variables do not exist in the current context.

I have tried putting public in front of the two strings, but then I get an error saying it's an invalid expression term.

Any suggestions would be great, thank you

Comment: use a `Literal` control.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your variables are scoped locally to just that one method.  In order for an inheriting object (the page) to see them, they need to be `protected` (or above) class-level members.  Something like this:

```
protected string FirstName { get; set; }
protected string LastName { get; set; }
```

Then in your method:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // get the user's name from active dirctory
    var user = UserPrincipal.Current;

    FirstName = user.GivenName;
    LastName = user.Surname;
}
```

And on the page:

```
<p class="text-center"><strong><% =FirstName %> <% =LastName %></strong></p>
```